# What is the difference between local runtime and hosted runtime in Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I I just started using Google Colab for a project of mine. I see an button of "CONNECT" on the web page that presents before me two options:

1. Connect to Hosted Runtime
2. Connect to Local Runtime

Can anyone explain what the two mean and how it may affect my project? I did not find any useful documentation related to it.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` (and there is a specific tag for `google-colaboratory`) - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Hosted Runtime runs on a new machine instance in Google Cloud. You don't need to set-up any hardware. But you may need to install a few libraries every time you use it.

Local Runtime runs on your machine at home. You need to install Python, Jupyter, and set-up some forwarding. It is useful if you have a lot of data to process locally, or if you have your own powerful GPU to use.

In most cases, I use Hosted Runtime.